# Set cookie depending on time

Tags: php

I have a simple poll site. I would like to disallow possibility of voting tomorrow a 0:00. I was thinking of doing it in a following way:

- check the time of page loading
- if it is greater than 2012-03-10 0:00 than `setcookie ("allow", "0");`
- than depending on `$_COOKIE["allow"];` allow or disallow voting (this part I have already done)

Is it correct way? Could you help me with setting cookie depended on time?

Comment: Why aren't you validating the vote *when it happens*? After all, the client browser doesn't *have to* react to your cookie (e.g. scripting may be disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope ! This is not a correct way to do it, because if users delete their cookies (or if they do not accept cookies at all), they will never be prevented from voting.

Instead, check the time on the server before accepting a vote. If it is still time to accept votes, well, accept it, otherwise discard it.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to do it in that way after yours and @Rowland Shaw's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a correct way.
Read setcookie function documentation, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php